# sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked while import ipdb

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

When I import ipdb, I seen below error message.

> import ipdb
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/auto/xr_pi/PRODUCTION/pyATS/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipdb/**main**.py", line 32, in 
>       get_ipython
>   NameError: name 'get_ipython' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/auto/xr_pi/PRODUCTION/pyATS/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipdb/**init**.py", line 16, in 
>       from ipdb.**main** import set_trace, post_mortem, pm, run, runcall, runeval, launch_ipdb_on_exception
>     File "/auto/xr_pi/PRODUCTION/pyATS/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipdb/**main**.py", line 51, in 
>       ipshell = InteractiveShellEmbed()
>     File "/auto/xr_pi/PRODUCTION/pyATS/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 68, in **init**
>       super(InteractiveShellEmbed,self).**init**(**kw)
>     File "/auto/xr_pi/PRODUCTION/pyATS/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 513, in **init**
>       self.init_history()
>     File "/auto/xr_pi/PRODUCTION/pyATS/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 1636, in init_history
>       self.history_manager = HistoryManager(shell=self, parent=self)
>     File "/auto/xr_pi/PRODUCTION/pyATS/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/history.py", line 520, in **init**
>       self.new_session()
>     File "", line 2, in new_session
>     File "/auto/xr_pi/PRODUCTION/pyATS/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/history.py", line 68, in needs_sqlite
>       return f(self, *a, **kw)
>     File "/auto/xr_pi/PRODUCTION/pyATS/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/history.py", line 538, in new_session
>       NULL, "") """, (datetime.datetime.now(),))
>   sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could it be, that you have already the database open somewhere inside the program or even an open cursor? If not, is there an other program still running accessing the db?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the first exception "NameError: name 'get_ipython' is not defined" on Python 3.3.5 with IPython 5.1.0, **it was gone when I switched to IPython 4.2.1** (check https://stackoverflow.com/a/39501284/4571444).

At the time the question was asked both IPython 5.0 and 4.0 were already released (https://ipython.org/news.html).

I'd suggest the topic name to be updated with the first exception, the second is might be caused by inproper handling of the first.